# load json file with loadJSON p5.js

Tags: javascript, json, p5.js

When i try to use this function I get the following error message. loadjson is not defined; please fix or add /*global loadjson*/. Am i doing something wrong or is there a better way to load a json file in javascript? I have tried several methods from youtube videos but none seem to work for me.

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.2.0/p5.js"></script>
<script>
    function preload(){
       loadJSON("/home/ubuntu/project/jason/data.json",gotData);
       }
    function gotData(data){
       println(data);
       }
</script>
```

Here is the format of my json file:

```
[{"date": "2020/07/28", "mass": 68.3}, {"date": "2020/07/29", "mass": 68.3}, {"date": "2020/07/30", "mass": 69.5},...]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code is perfectly fine, P5.js just requires a setup (or draw) function to work.

Also `println` doesn't exist in javascript (or P5.js) just use `console.log(data)`

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.2.0/p5.js"></script>
<script>
    function setup() {
      noLoop();
    }
    function preload(){
       loadJSON("/home/ubuntu/project/jason/data.json",gotData);
    }
    function gotData(data){
       console.log(data);
    }
</script>
```